# How to find an email pattern in an HTML file using bash

Tags: html, bash, email, sequence

I have a number of HTML files which contain a huge number of email addresses (at least 50 each), and I'd like to write a bash script to process the files, and then print the addresses to a .txt file, but I'm not sure how to actually find the email address sequence (e.g what would a regex for an email address pattern look like).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "email sequence"? Are you looking for email addresses or actual emails? If the latter, you need to show an example of an input file (you should probably do that anyway).

Comment: No, I'm looking for the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
perl -MEmail::Find -nle 'find_emails $_, sub { print $_[1] }' *.html
```

I'm not sure where you'd even start doing this in pure bash.